# Borel Measures: Riesz-Markov-Kakutani

Tags: integration, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

**Problem**

Given a locally compact Hausdorff space.

Consider a positive functional:
$$I:\mathcal{C}_0(\Omega)\to\mathbb{C}:\quad f\geq0\implies I f\geq0$$

Then it has a representation via a regular Borel measure:
$$If=\int f\mathrm{d}\mu:\quad\mu(E)=\inf_{E\subseteq U}\mu(U)\quad\mu(U)=\sup_{K\subseteq U}\mu(K)\quad(\mu(K)<\infty)$$
How to prove this from scratch?

**Attempt**

Start by assigning a size to opens:
$$\mu(U):=\sup\left\{\Lambda h:h\in\mathcal{C}_0(\Omega):\,h\leq\chi_U\,(\mathrm{supp}h\subseteq U)\right\}$$
and take as outer measure:
$$\mu(A):=\inf_{A\subseteq U}\mu(U):\quad\mu(A)\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu(A_k)\quad\left(A\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right)$$
*(Note that these definitions don't clash.)*

The measurable sets include all opens:
$$U\in\mathcal{T}:\quad\mu(A)=\mu(A\cap U)+\mu(A\cap U^\complement)$$

Also it follows that integrating has the same effect:
$$f\geq0:\quad\varepsilon\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}\mu(\{f\geq n\varepsilon\})\leq If,\int f\mathrm{d}\mu\leq\varepsilon\sum_{k=0}^{K}\mu(\{f\geq n\varepsilon\})$$

Finally it is outer regular by construction; but what about inner regularity?

**Lemma**

Especially, I have in petto:
$$h\in\mathcal{C}_0(\Omega):\quad \chi_A\leq h\implies \mu(A)\leq Ih$$
$$h\in\mathcal{C}_0(\Omega):\quad h\leq\chi_K\implies Ih\leq\mu(K)$$
But how to applies this for inner regularity?

Comment: You may be too optimistic in thinking that a simple proof is out there.